# ESB 4.8 is released, but Developer studio is still 3.2 and some artifacts are incompatible

Tags: wso2

The Message Processor template for Developer Studio 3.2 is incompatible with changes for ESB 4.8. Searching I found some documentation trail that suggests that there is a version 3.3 of Developer studio that addesses these incompatibilities. However it is now available from the download site:

http://dist.wso2.org/p2/developer-studio/releases/

shows up to 3.2
Any ideas when  Developer Studio 3.3 will be available for download?

Answer (score 2):

We are planning to release Developer Studio 3.3.0 with in the next 2 weeks time (Before the  X'mas). It is possible we will rename it to Developer Studio 3.5 release given the amount of new features and improvements we have done.

You may download the latest Alpha 4 version from [[1]](http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.5.0/Alpha4/).

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: It will support Juno SR2. We will make the Kepler compatibility once Kepler SR2 is released in March 2014 because it will be the most stable Kepler release.

Answer (score 0):

Developer studio 3.3.0 is not there in the download site since the final version has not been released yet. 
(There's an alpha version under testing which can be found from the [mailing list here](http://wso2.markmail.org/search/?q=list%3aorg.wso2.dev%20developer%20studio%203.3.0#query%3alist%3aorg.wso2.dev%20developer%20studio%203.3.0%20page:1%20mid%3amsd7uexm5q5rfa33%20state%3aresults).)